# merging object literals/json in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to join all of the data objects into one where they are all chained

```
var person1 = {
    hello: {
        "david": {
            "hours": "44",
            "money": "22"
        }
    }
};


var person2 = {
    world: {
        "pearce": {
            "hours": "21",
            "money": "11"
        }
    }
};
```

I want it to look like this:

```
var mergedObjects = {
    hello: {
        "david": {
            "hours": "44",
            "money": "22"
        }
    },
    world: {
        "pearce": {
            "hours": "21",
            "money": "11"
        }
    }
};
```

I know how to do this with Arrays, but how can i do this in javascript as a JSON object maintaining the correct structure

Comment: Did you mean to have data appear twice in your output? That won't be a valid JS object.

Comment: you can't do that... key in an object will be unique.. I'll advice using an array to store this structure

Comment: It's worth noting that a Javascript Array is perfectly valid JSON as well, in the event that you're just looking to find something that works as JSON.

Comment: sorry have updated, that was a bad example, was trying to merge children of the two objects into one

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: Did you mean to tag jquery? You could use `$.extend(merged,person1,person2);`

Answer (score 1):

Check this out....

Answer is present here...[How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically/383245#383245)

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tAqLL/2/)

**JS:**

```
 function mergeRecursive(obj1, obj2) {

  for (var p in obj2) {
    try {
      // Property in destination object set; update its value.
      if ( obj2[p].constructor==Object ) {
        obj1[p] = mergeRecursive(obj1[p], obj2[p]);

      } else {
        obj1[p] = obj2[p];

      }

    } catch(e) {
      // Property in destination object not set; create it and set its value.
      obj1[p] = obj2[p];

    }
  }

  return obj1;
}

var person1 = {
    hello: {
        "david": {
            "hours": "44",
            "money": "22"
        }
    }
};


var person2 = {
    world: {
        "pearce": {
            "hours": "21",
            "money": "11"
        }
    }
};

console.log(mergeRecursive(person1, person2));
```

Comment: This code is taken from this answer, verbatim: http://stackoverflow.com/a/383245/610573 -- please give credit when using code you didn't write.

Answer (score 0):

check this post : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

```
var person1 = {
    hello: {
        "david": {
            "hours": "44",
            "money": "22"
        }
    }
};


var person2 = {
    world: {
        "pearce": {
            "hours": "21",
            "money": "11"
        }
    }
};


function merge_options(obj1,obj2){
    var obj3 = {};
    for (var attrname in obj1) { obj3[attrname] = obj1[attrname]; }
    for (var attrname in obj2) { obj3[attrname] = obj2[attrname]; }
    return obj3;
}



merge_options(person1,person2);
```

Comment: This code is taken directly from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/171256/610573 -- please give credit when using code you didn't write.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with jQuery:

```
var person1 = {
    hello: {
        "david": {
            "hours": "44",
            "money": "22"
         }
    }
};


var person2 = {
    world: {
        "pearce": {
            "hours": "21",
            "money": "11"
        }
    }
};

var mergedObjects = $.extend({}, person1, person2);

console.dir(mergedObjects);
```